# Apache server fails to start when adding a new virtual host

Tags: apache, centos7, virtual, hosts

I currently have a CentOS 7 server on Linode running Apache2 with two domains pointed at it. I have achieved this by configuring name-based virtual hosts in  /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf

This has worked great, but...

For some reason, when I add a third virtual host to this file, apache refuses to start. I've created all of the appropriate folders in /var/www/html/... with appropriate permissions (apache.apache). But Apache still refuses to start. Below is sample of my vhost.conf file and the error logs from apache. What step am I missing?

Here's my vhost.conf...

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/domain1.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/domain1.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain2.com
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/domain2.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/domain2.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain3.com
    ServerName domain3.com
    ServerAlias www.domain3.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain3.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/domain3.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/domain3.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the error I get from apache...

```
Jan 16 18:40:30 dribrats systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 16 18:40:30 dribrats httpd[19023]: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:1
Jan 16 18:40:30 dribrats httpd[19023]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Jan 16 18:40:30 dribrats systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 16 18:40:30 dribrats kill[19024]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jan 16 18:40:30 dribrats systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 16 18:40:30 dribrats systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 16 18:40:30 dribrats systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 16 18:40:30 dribrats systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I've figured it out. The problems stemmed from my permissions for the new folder for the third domain. I didn't set the correct permissions. Running the following commands fixed my problem.

```
sudo chown apache:apache -R /var/www/html/example.com/

cd /var/www/html/example.com/
find . -type f -exec sudo chmod 0644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec sudo chmod 0755 {} \;
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/example.com -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/example.com -R
```

Then restart apache...

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```